# Calendar to Cal displaying schedule

Tags: freebsd, calendar, cal

I don't understand how to create a txt to use the calendar utility to display "notes"

Comment: `echo "test text" > txt` will create a file called `txt` with the contents of `test text`, but I think your question is more complex than that. There are also a heap of other ways to make a file with text as the content. For example the text editor `vi` is installed by default in FreeBSD, but how to use `vi` is another question.

Comment: What should be the content of the desired txt? What have you tried?

Comment: @Zumo I think that's the intent of the question. Looking at the FreeBSD `calendar` manpage it's not clear at all how one would add notes to a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit a text file, use whatever editor you have available, or install one.  `nano`, `emacs`, and `vi` are common ones.

If the calendar utility we're talking about here is the command `calendar` as described [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=calendar&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html), then the format of the file is described by [the manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=calendar&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html).

The file should be called `.calendar` (with a leading dot) and be placed in your home directory.

Comment: I figured it was syntax thing,   ".calendar"

Comment: Below roaima's example use jan/17 as a format recognized by the "calendar" cmd. hmmmm that's interesting. i wonder if i could change that to a more military format:  ddMMMyy   example 19JAN17

Comment: @Hy19r0 You should `man calendar`, read it to figure out what formats it supports, and then test.

Answer (score 1):

The `calendar` text file is a plain text file with its various date formats described in great detail in the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=calendar&sektion=1).

What's not so clear is how one adds notes to the date formats. Here is a simple example of this. Put the following three lines into the file `$HOME/calendar`. (Use <kbd>tab</kbd> between the date and a note, and at the beginning of a continuation line.)

```
Jan/17  Answer a couple of questions on unix.stackexchange
        Team meeting first thing
Jan/21  Restart the servers
```

Now run `calendar` and if you're doing this on 17th January (any year) you'll get the first two lines. When you run it on 21st January you'll get the third line.

If you run `calendar -A3` you'll get today's notes plus those for the next three days (if any).